# IF any shops decreases its sales 3 times consecutively. Solution in HIVE or SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

[image]

IF any shops decreases its sale 3 times consecutively -> print the shop name.

```
     python algo:
      1> sort by date.
      loop
      3> select shop(i) if not in list(visited), 
          check if its sale decrease 
          for 3 times consecutively, 
          if yes -> print the shop name.
      2> append shopName in visited.
```

Is there a way to do this in HIVE or SQL?

Comment: What's your expect result from you sample data?

Comment: You have A/1 repeated on two rows.  What does that mean?

Comment: @D-Shih  
IF any shops decreases its sale 3 times consecutively -> print the shop name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the correction, I have edited the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive, you can use `lag` and `lead` to get the values on previous and next rows and use them for comparison.

```
select distinct shop
from (select t.*
      ,lag(sales) over(partition by shop order by date) as prev_sales
      ,lead(sales) over(partition by shop order by date) as next_sales
      from tbl t
     ) t
where prev_sales > sales and sales > next_sales
```

Comment: thanks for answering. This is a dumpy data, but if I want sales decrease for  20 days consecutively, how to do in "WHERE " ?